# Looping animation relatively to the end of the previous cycle?

Tags: animation, looping

I have animated (keyframed) a gear rotating around one axis in one direction (say from 0° to 140° around the axis passing perpendicularly through the center of the gear) and then it rotates back, but not exactly at the same initial state (say from 140° to 20° around the same axis). Furthermore, in each part, the gear has a different, non constant, rotational speed.

Now, I would like to be able to loop this animation relatively to the gear state at the end of this cycle (i.e. now rotate from 20° to 160° and go back from 160° to 40° in the same way, and so on...).

I added a Cycles Modifier to each component of the rotation (in quaternions if that matters) and set the Before/After settings to Repeat with Offset, but during the animation, the rotation angle decreases to the point where the gear does almost nothing (so I guess I'm misunderstanding what this is supposed to do).